# Curl Spring complex object is null

Tags: spring, curl

I am using Spring boot to develop a REST application.

Significant code looks like this:

```
Controller
@PostMapping(value = "/addUpdateNewsItem")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addUpdateNewsItem(
        @RequestBody NimbusNewsDto dto,
        Principal principal) {

the DTO:
public class NimbusNewsDto {
    private String userDn;
    private NimbusNewsJson newsItem;

NimbusNewsJson:
    private String nimbusId;
    private String subject;
    private String description;
    private String creator;
    private String createDate;
    private String expirationDate;


Curl:
curl -k -d @newsItem1.json -H "Content-Type: Application/json"  http://localhost:8443/baseline/news/addUpdateNewsItem 

the data:
{"newsDto":{
    "userDn": "localhost",
    "newsItem": {
        "nimbusId": "nimbusId1",
        "subject": "subject1",
        "description": "Hello I am the first news item",
        "creator": "God",
        "createDate": "23/Jul/2020:02:15:11",
        "expirationDate": ""
    }
}}
```

I took a while to get past formatting errors causing 'bad request', etc.. Now when I make the call and debug the code I see that the dto object has the two items, both of which are null. I've tried multiple combinations of " and ' and escaped characters, all with no luck.

I'm running the Ubuntu shell under windows, and the spring code is running on Tomcat.

Suggestions? The last time I ran into this I ended up breaking up the DTO object into multiple parameters, but I rather just have the DTO as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the json you are sending does not "match" the dto, there is an extra object that "wraps" your dto.

you have to remove this part:

```
{
  "newsDto": {
  ...
}
```

like this:

```
{
  "userDn": "localhost",
  "newsItem": {
    "nimbusId": "nimbusId1",
    "subject": "subject1",
    "description": "Hello I am the first news item",
    "creator": "God",
    "createDate": "23/Jul/2020:02:15:11",
    "expirationDate": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that particular combination but obviously I did not. Thank you!